# How to loop over a two dimensional char array

Tags: c

I have 2 two dimensional arrays. At some point, I need to pick one of the two and loop over it. What kind of pointer do I need to point to a 2 dimensional array in order to loop over it ?

```c
const char *a[] = {
            "example1",
            "example2",
            NULL
        };

const char *b[] = {
            "example1",
            "example2",
            "example3",
            "example4",
            "example5",
            NULL
        };

const char *pointer = a;

int count = 0;
while(pointer != NULL)
{
    puts(pointer[count]);

    count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need one more `*`:

```
const char **pointer = a;
```

Your loop condition is wrong too - I think you want:

```
while (pointer[count] != NULL)
```